# How to ensure that my key bindings have priority over other definitions

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, rcp

I am developing an RCP app. The app has an execution mode where I want to enable various key bindings to control Start, Stop, Continue, Repeat etc. The bindings will be enabled using an 'ExecutionContext' which is set when any of the relevant views are activated.

The context switching is done in each of the 'Execution' views.

```java
@Override
public final void createPartControl(Composite parent)
{
    addPartListener();

    ...
}

private void addPartListener()
{
    this.getViewSite().getPage().addPartListener(new IPartListener2()
    {
        IContextActivation token = null;

        @Override
        public void partDeactivated(IWorkbenchPartReference partRef)
        {
            if (token != null)
            {
                System.out.println("End exec context");
                IContextService contextService = (IContextService) PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService(
                        IContextService.class);
                contextService.deactivateContext(token);
                token = null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void partActivated(IWorkbenchPartReference partRef)
        {
            System.out.println("Set exec context");
            IContextService contextService = (IContextService) PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService(
                    IContextService.class);
            token = contextService.activateContext("AtfExecutionContext");
        }
    });

}
```

I can see via Console messages that my context is being set and some of the key bindings are working as expected.

However, if a key binding has already been assigned from another plugin, that binding has priority. E.g. I want to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> to stop but when that is pressed I get the 'Next perspective' action which is the workbench default.

The binding definition is

```xml
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.bindings">
      <scheme
            id="atfscheme"
            name="atfscheme"
            parentId="org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration">
      </scheme>
      <key
            commandId="com.xxx.atf.model.ui.commands.ExecKey.Start"
            contextId="AtfExecutionContext"
            schemeId="atfscheme"
            sequence="M1+M2+F5">
<!-- F5 does not work but Ctrl-Shift-F5 does -->
      </key>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.contexts">
      <context
            id="AtfExecutionContext"
            name="AtfExecutionContext"
            parentId="org.eclipse.debug.ui.debugging">
<!-- have tried various parentid values... -->
      </context>
   </extension>
```

It seems that only previously undefined accelerators work. What do I have to do to override existing definitions and activate mine when my context has been set?

Comment: How exactly are you enabling the context?

Comment: @greg-449 added code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a separate context service for each part, you must use the correct context service.

It isn't necessary to activate / deactivate the context on part activation / deactivation. The separate context services will deal with that automatically.

So activate in `createPartControl` with:

```java
IContextService contextService = getSite().getService(IContextService.class);

token = contextService.activateContext("AtfExecutionContext");
```

and deactivate when the part closes.

You are also defining a new key binding scheme - that has to be activated separately and isn't what you want here. Just remove that and just use `org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration` as the `schemeId`

Comment: Thanks. I did as you suggested but still no joy. I get a debug message which confirms that the context is set.  I clicked on the part to ensure that it has focus. Do I need to set a context parentId or is it optional?

Comment: The parent is optional but is most often `org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window` (Windows) or `org.eclipse.ui.contexts.dialogAndWindow` (Dialog and Windows)

Comment: You are also defining the keys in a key binding scheme - which would have to be activated  separately (this is for things like the 'Emacs' key bindings) - remove the key scheme and just use `org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration`

Comment: just came to the same conclusion :-) thanks a lot for your help. It's working now!